# Improving on triple exponential smoothing H-W approach in R

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting

I recently forecasted data using the H-W triple exp smoothing method which takes into account seasonality and trend. 
The data I used was weekly data which presented number of phone calls a restaurant receives. I wanted to forecast (using 45 weeks of data), at least 10 weeks ahead.

This was my code:

```
orders_hw <- HoltWinters(calls)
library(forecast)
orders_hw_forecast <- forecast.HoltWinters(orders_hw, h = 70) #70 = 70 days or 10 weeks
plot.forecast(orders_hw_forecast)
```

The data I used is as follows(calls):

```
calls <- 
structure(c(568, 485, 360, 523, 514, 370, 332, 758, 580, 613, 
544, 568, 394, 389, 841, 685, 719, 647, 615, 389, 367, 744, 717, 
778, 594, 551, 354, 317, 731, 721, 819, 662, 581, 436, 394, 779, 
770, 793, 763, 619, 412, 427, 865, 805, 952, 759, 677, 429, 424, 
935, 805, 915, 780, 685, 430, 404, 797, 733, 766, 747, 697, 446, 
334, 598, 868, 888, 849, 707, 458, 426, 950, 806, 826, 804, 730, 
541, 439, 1070, 770, 989, 863, 737, 525, 461, 982, 925, 906, 
877, 954, 532, 522, 1070, 918, 1010, 786, 787, 499, 410, 1041, 
863, 989, 833, 783, 506, 496, 1057, 1031, 983, 897, 783, 492, 
428, 927, 875, 913, 808, 655, 358, 356, 740, 581, 771, 722, 628, 
417, 442, 895, 791, 854, 779, 767, 513, 415, 916, 764, 1259, 
944, 797, 561, 552, 988, 982, 857, 289, 515, 337, 403, 895, 879, 
702, 778, 721, 515, 572, 912, 873, 892, 847, 775, 535, 565, 1047, 
933, 965, 931, 795, 628, 421, 444, 361, 788, 680, 619, 464, 451, 
861, 851, 801, 780, 672, 486, 412, 1049, 1132, 1022, 905, 758, 
574, 516, 1045, 1107, 1177, 1068, 1044, 640, 718, 755, 772, 798, 
817, 779, 540, 463, 1002, 970, 1033, 992, 748, 527, 475, 935, 
853, 983, 985, 880, 548, 631, 996, 1041, 1184, 1015, 905, 641, 
547, 1121, 1255, 1235, 1087, 1046, 662, 711, 1216, 1370, 1404, 
1233, 1464, 973, 587, 980, 1202, 997, 1022, 876, 552, 549, 1018, 
966, 876, 1139, 962, 682, 685, 1311, 1289, 1220, 1227, 1105, 
758, 667, 1258, 1511, 1509, 1462, 1185, 834, 946, 1149, 975, 
919, 949, 883, 555, 502, 1055, 979, 1048, 938, 825, 519, 351, 
574, 983, 989, 1116, 927, 707, 588, 1111, 1042, 1096, 1034, 860, 
600, 528, 1052, 1019, 1036, 1154, 1043, 740, 570, 1042, 990, 
1149, 1063, 895, 579, 503, 1103, 1073, 1081, 1017, 882, 632, 
602), .Tsp = c(1, 7.97777777777778, 45), class = "ts")
```

What I noticed from this data was (after conducting a p-test for the residuals), my  p-value was `2.2e-16` (`acf(orders_hw_forecast$residuals, lag.max=20)`). Thus, I think there may be a better method to forecast above data (for calls). I'm not sure what kind of changes I can make to get more accurate results.

Comment: Small tip: If you type `dput(calls)` and copy-paste the output into your question, the data can just be copy-pasted back into `R` and used immediately. That's very convenient for producing reproducible code.

Comment: If I think my data is limited (for example only 300 or so points), should I use bootstrap?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason you have set the period of seasonality to 45 rather than 7. Try the following:

```
library(forecast)
calls <- ts(calls, frequency=7)
fit1 <- HoltWinters(calls)
fcast1 <- forecast(fit1, h=70)
plot(fcast1)
```

Even better, use an ARIMA model which works pretty well here:

```
fit2 <- auto.arima(calls)
fcast2 <- forecast(fit2, h=70)
plot(fcast2)
```

[image]

The decreasing oscillations in the forecast period does not mean the seasonality will get less. It is telling you that the positions of the peaks and troughs become more uncertain over time. The blue line gives you the means of the forecast distributions. Note the size of the prediction intervals which measures the uncertainty in the forecast distributions.

Comment: Where can I find the exact math behind H-W and the ARIMA you used? Thank You.